# Doxygen : Section id only alphanumerical since 1.8.15-git

Tags: doxygen

I am working on this project : https://sbl.inria.fr/doc, where the documentation is done with **doxygen**.

We were used to define the id of our sections with the symbol "-" to separate the words, for example :

```
\section sec-intro Introduction
```

However, it looks like the convention has changed since doxygen 1.8.15-git and only alpha-numerical characters are accepted, breaking almost all the pages in our documentation.

Unfortunately, we have a large number of pages, and before reviewing the whole documentation, I wanted to know if there is anything that I am missing, like a doxygen option to turn ON / OFF

[edit]

Here is a minimal example that does not work for me, with doxygen 1.8.15-git:

```
/**
\mainpage My Main Page

Abstract

\section home-intro Introduction

Intro
*/

//! Documented class test
class test{
};
```

I just create the configuration file and then run doxygen on the directory containing my .hpp file (so that there is no need to specify the path to my header) :

```
doxygen -g; doxygen
```

The main page on the output html contains "Abstract", but not the section, and there is a warning in the doxygen log :

```
test.hpp:6: warning: Invalid section id `home'; ignoring section
```

[edit 2]

It worked with doxygen 1.8.14. I cloned the project from the git repository, so I had the latest version. Using the tag version for the 1.8.14, it works fine. I changed the title.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but didn't succeed. Can you give a small example showing the problem?

Comment: I added a minimal example in the description. Thanks.

Comment: I think the important note here is the version (we shouldn't call it 1.8.15 but 1.8.15-git as it is not yet released, I corrected this). I see the problems as well, I have to dive into it. Regarding the SBL stuff it is probably easy to fix as here is a heavy usage of aliases where something with a `-` is appended replacing the `-` with a `_` might solve some problems here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem, it is a regression on:
`Bug 740046 - Negative sign in -Foo::Bar ruins hyperlink in generated output`

The github issue causing the problem is https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/5677 and the pull request https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/704.

The issue has been fixed in the proposed patch: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6388

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just as a side note, it is not clear in the documentation what are the possible characters for the id. From https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdpage , on the "\page" command referred by the "\section" command, it says that only letters and digits are used while it is not the case. Is it a recommandation or a specification ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it is just a recommendation from the past, but I think it are still wise words as special signs (and notably '-' as used for arithmetic operations as well) are likely to give problem (as you noted ;-) ).